# excel vba regain focus following external hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel 2010, my macro attempts to load 2 external websites, the data from which I can enter into my table

```
Sub Call_TreasuryBonds()
    Dim szCeladdrs As String
    Dim rFoundcell As Range

    ChDir "\\Mac\Home\DOCUMENTS\FOLIO\BONDS"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="Treasury Rates.xlsm"
    Sheets("TreasRates").Select

    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Range("F2").Value
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Range("F3").Value
```

1st hyperlink is: https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yield
2nd hyperlink is: https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=realyield

the first website loads without difficulty, but on attempting to load the second, i receive an error message:
    'Run-time error '5'; Invalid procedure call or argument', 
and I am unable to return focus to my workbook.

What to do, please?

Comment: what about producing a minimal working example showing the issue?

Comment: i have modified the entry, providing code preceding the call to hyperlink, together with full address of the hyperlink above

Comment: @rick: if the 2nd link gives you a problem, please also specify that one.  it might very well be there's an URL encoding error in it or such?

Comment: also note that you attempt to open the link noted as the `value` of these cells; if the cells themselves are formatted as a hyperlink, then their value (their visible content) could be different from what they target (i.e. the real link URL).

Comment: Hi Carl. I have inserted the txt of 2nd hyperlink. Both cells are formatted as hyperlinks, and the visible text is identical to relevant hyperlink address.

Answer (score 0):

Please Change :

```
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Range("F2").Value
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Range("F3").Value
```

with this:

```
Range("F2").Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
Range("F3").Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
```

Comment: Appears to work perfectly, many thanks Nikolaos. One further Q, if you have time; in each case the hyperlink opens a new window. If one wanted a new tab in existing window, what to change? Thanks again, R.

Comment: if you have your browser opened the hyperlinks will open in the existing window